# How to use Angular 4 with PHP routes?

Tags: php, angular, routes

I created a blank new project on Angular 4 (with angular-cli) in order to try to use it with PHP Routes, I'm using [Phroute Fast route](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute).

Before trying this I used to call the whole file with a param to call a specific function, like this:

**angular service**

```
apiGet(): any {
    return this._http.get('api/server/user.php?action=getUser');
}
```

I tried to install the Phroute but it didn't worked, when I try to call it like the code bellow, I get the following error:

```
apiGet(): any {
    return this._http.get('api/user');
}
```

> GET http://localhost/api/index.php net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

---

***Folder structure***:

- api/

  - server/ `(used to call files with extensions)`
  - vendor/
  - index.php
- index.html
- bundle.js
- [..other angular files..]

***index.php***

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

function processInput($uri) {
    $uri = implode('/', array_slice(
        explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 3
    ));

    return $uri;
}

function processOutput($response){
    echo json_encode($response);    
}

$router = new Phroute\RouteCollector(new Phroute\RouteParser);

$router->get('user', function(){ 
    return 'Hello, PHRoute!';   
});

$dispatcher = new Phroute\Dispatcher(router);

try {
    $response = $dispatcher->dispatch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], processInput($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
} catch (Phroute\Exception\HttpRouteNotFoundException $e) {
    var_dump($e);      
    die();
} catch (Phroute\Exception\HttpMethodNotAllowedException $e) {
    var_dump($e);       
    die();
}

processOutput($response);
```

***.htaccess***

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api
    RewriteRule ^ /api/index.php [L,R]

    # This code needs to be used in order to enable refresh
    # and redirects on the Angular routes
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** Keep in mind I'm very new to this PHP route concept, so any other advice is also welcome!

So I'd like to know how do I properly configure this to make it work? I didn't found any tutorial on this topic, so it was very confusing to me.

Comment: The redirect is caused by the `R` flag in your htaccess `[L,R]`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone now I'm getting an error `Class 'Phroute\RouteCollector' not found in ` but everything was installed according to the php package

Comment: Because your not using `use`, the namespace would be `new Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;`

Comment: When in doubt, always check your `./vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file for reference.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone now i got `Use of undefined constant router - assumed 'router'`, and when I change it to `$router` instead of `router` i get this error: `Argument 1 passed to Phroute\Phroute\Dispatcher::__construct() must be an instance of Phroute\Phroute\RouteDataInterface`. Sorry to bother you, but this is all new to me and I really want to learn how this works.

Comment: Ok a quick look on [GitHub](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getData&type=) you should be using `$router->getData()` instead. If you track that method back your indeed see it returns an interface [RouteDataArray](https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute/blob/3cc5ae4bb5088cfa5f8e4919873316ff57cfe09c/src/Phroute/RouteCollector.php#L390) https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RouteDataArray&type=

Comment: I don't normally suggest libraries, but if you want something which is much simpler, id look into `https://fatfreeframework.com` It would suit what you're trying todo with less code and also has more features once you start to build out the backend. There are other like silex or slim.. really just need a micro framework with routing (without needing to implement all the base logic)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's going.. Now I'm getting this error `Route does not exist in phroute\phroute\src\Phroute\Dispatcher.php on line 218`. About your comment on the library, actually i'm just looking for a routing system for PHP.

Comment: Im not sure what that is, but if you google it you can see 100 odd sites are broken with that error, https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Route+does+not+exist+in+phroute%5Cphroute%5Csrc%5CPhroute%5CDispatcher.php+on+line+218 . about the other suggestions you can use just the routing in fatfree it uses closures like your doing in like 3 lines of code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'll do that. I'm going to study other libs of php routes. What caught my attention was the fact that this one is "fast", so since this is my first try, I tought it woul be easier. But thanks for the hints.